# Form control invalid with ngbDatePicker

Tags: angular, ngb-datepicker

I have the following input and works normally to save

```
<input id="field_dataAtivacao" type="text" class="form-control" name="dataAtivacao"
               ngbDatepicker #dataAtivacaoDp="ngbDatepicker" formControlName="dataAtivacao"
               [value]="dataAtivacao | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'" placeholder="00/00/0000"
               [disabled]="false" [readonly]="true" />
```

Form control

```
  editForm = this.fb.group({
        dataAtivacao: [],
    });
```

The value that comes from `cliente.dataAtivacao` is a normal date using this format `00/00/0000`. It is loaded when the user click to edit.

```
this.editForm.patchValue({
      dataAtivacao: cliente.dataAtivacao,
});
```

The issue occurs when I need to update the value of form control because the button is enable only when I click in input and set date again but I need to update without click again to set a date because the date already was loaded.

```
<button type="submit" id="save-entity"
        [disabled]="editForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span>Save</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Why are you using value attribute in html?

Comment: Is it the issue?

Comment: yes when you use reactive form you don't need value attribute to update the value. patchvalue will internally update the value.

Comment: but now does'nt show the value in input the input show just the placeholder

Comment: In which place you patching value in code?

Comment: on the `ngOnInit()` and I call activatedRoute.data inside it

Comment: and the button keeps disabled

Comment: Can you send the cliente.dataAtivacao data format?

Comment: in this way `2019-12-13`

Comment: You need to specify dataAtivacao as an object (structure) with the year, month and day properties as mentioned in the : https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1736

Comment: ok I need to convert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204224/discussion-between-renan-martins-and-chellappan).